# Error handling not working for Nodemailer in Express

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have a function to read mails using nodemailer:**MailRead.js**

```
exports.sendMailService = async (mailOptions) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mailOptions.from = 'someemail@some.com'
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: some,
            auth: {
                user: 'somemail@some.com',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("error is " + error);
                resolve(false); // or use rejcet(false) but then you will have to handle errors
            }
            else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                resolve(true);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

When I'm calling this function in a controller :**sendController.js**

```
exports.sendMail = async (req, res, next) => {
    const mailBody = req.body
    try{
        await sendMailService(mailOptions)
        //if I do this:
        //const mailSent = await sendMailService(mailOptions)
        //if every credential is correct it mailSent displays true if not credentials false it gives 
        //false
        //but I want to handle error not just check for condition.
    }catch (err){ //not coming to catch part
        next(ApiError.badClientError('Bad Credentials')); //some function to handle error
            return;
    }
};
```

When an api is call : above function is triggered :

Apisample:

```
api.post('sendmail',sendMail);
```

Also I tried [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61562131/why-wont-error-handling-work-in-nodemailer): but I don't think its working for me.

So is there any suggestion on false credentials it should go to catch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sendMail()` function is assuming that a failed call to `sendMailService()` will reject the promise it returns.  But, upon error, your `sendMailService()` function calls `resolve(false)`, not `reject(someError)`.  Thus, your `await sendMailService()` never throws and you never get to your `catch` block.

If instead, you reject upon error, it will then get to your `catch` block:

```
exports.sendMailService = async (mailOptions) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mailOptions.from = 'someemail@some.com'
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: some,
            auth: {
                user: 'somemail@some.com',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("error is ", error);
                // reject the returned promise with the error
                reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                resolve(true);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much...…Sorry I finally understood where I was making mistake.....