# Handle and pass errors from Nodemailer sendMail

Tags: node.js, error-handling, nodemailer

Tried these solution

- https://nodemailer.com/about/#example
- [Why won't error handling work in nodemailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61562131/why-wont-error-handling-work-in-nodemailer)
- [Nodemailer email confirmation using Async/Await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508261/nodemailer-email-confirmation-using-async-await)

Nothing worked. So I', trying to throw my own exception from within  sendMail errors like this

```
try{  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
        if(error){
            console.log(`couldn't send mail ${error}`);
            throw 500;
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: %s', response);
        }       
  });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error =' + error);
    }
```

I'm getting an error:

```
throw 500;
^
500
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How can I return a response success or error to my client?

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, try/catch block **does not catch** an exception that is throwed from a callback in a function which returns a promise.

`transporter.sendMail` function returns a promise. So, try/catch block can not catch the exception from the callback function.

You can do this, instead;

```js
try {
  const response = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  console.log('Message sent: %s', response);
        
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error =' + error);
  throw 500; // or throw Error("your error message");
}
```