# Add return type to a signature in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Have I added correctly return type to a signature?

before adding:

```
export const sendEmail = async (
  mailOptions: MailOptions
) => {
  await smtpTransport.send(mailOptions);
};
```

after adding:

```
export const sendEmail = async (
  mailOptions: MailOptions
) => {
  return await smtpTransport.send(mailOptions);
};
```

or I need it to do via Promise ?

Comment: A return type on a function signature looks like this: `smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions: string): string` ( : type at the end). I think you meant another thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the docs](https://openstapps.gitlab.io/core-tools/classes/_node_modules__types_nodemailer_lib_smtp_transport_d_.smtptransport.html#send), the method `send` has a return type of `void`. This suggests to me that your `await` will have no effect as it seems to be synchronous.

You can pass through a `callback: (err: Error | null, info: SentMessageInfo) => void`, you could use this to make an asynchronous function quite like [this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56508463/7298451) - or just use it how it is (probably best).

***If*** it was asynchronous, then it would return a `Promise<void>` with or without your return or the async wrapper:

```
export const sendEmail = async (
  mailOptions: MailOptions
): Promise<void> => {
  return await smtpTransport.send(mailOptions);
};
```

Or

```
export const sendEmail = (
  mailOptions: MailOptions
): Promise<void> => {
  return smtpTransport.send(mailOptions);
};
```

Or

```
export const sendEmail = async (
  mailOptions: MailOptions
): Promise<void> => {
  await smtpTransport.send(mailOptions);
};
```

*Notice the function's type signature.*

Comment: The first code would also return `Promise<void>`.

Comment: You're right, been a while since I've done ts. I'll update my answer. Thank-you